# Inserting millions of records with deduplication SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, deduplication

This is a theoretical scenario, and I am more than amateur when it comes to large scale SQL databases...

How would I go about inserting around 2million records into an existing database off 6million records (table1 into table2), whilst at the same time using email de-duplication (some subscribers may already exist in site2, but we don't want to insert those that already exist)?

I understand how to simply get the records from site 1 and add them into site 2, but how would we do this on such a large scale, and not causing data duplication? Any reading sources would be more than helpful for me, as ive found that a struggle.

i.e.:
**Table 1: site1Subscribers**

site1Subscribers(subID, subName, subEmail, subDob, subRegDate, subEmailListNum, subThirdParties)

**Table 2: site2Subscribers**

site2Subscribers(subID, subName, subEmail, subDob, subRegDate, subEmailListNum, subThirdParties)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL? DB2?

Comment: My set-up is a typical LAMP; mySQL under Linux Ubuntu (10).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
insert into site2Subscribers
select * from site1Subscribers s1
left outer join site2Subscribers s2
    on s1.subEmail = s2.subEmail
where s2.subEmail is null;
```

The `left outer join` along with the null check will return only those rows from `site1Subscribers` that have no matching entry in `site2Subscribers`.

Comment: Better yet, use `EXISTS` which translates into a slightly cheaper semi-join.

Comment: @usr: Have you any sources for that? I always wondered what to use.

Comment: I just noticed the cost difference in the execution plans. Maybe there isn't even a runtime difference, but why would the cost formulae differ if the runtime cost was identical? I should benchmark this...